# How to extend ViewPager2 with a dot indicator?

Tags: java, android, pagination, androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm currently working on a instruction manual, which does have pages - and uses `ViewPager2`.

So far I've found dot-indicators for `ViewPager`, but not for `ViewPager2`. I'd like to provide better visual feedback, so that one can see that there's more pages, to begin with. How to extend ViewPager2 with a dot indicator, with the least effort? This is not a request for off-site resources - despite my own answer uses a library. Feel free to add a better (more light-weight) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package [`me.relex:circleindicator`](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator) supports `ViewPager2` and is available on [`mavenCentral()`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.relex/circleindicator/2.1.6):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation "me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6"
}
```

One has to use class `CircleIndicator3` in the XML:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:ci_width="5dp"
    app:ci_height="5dp"
    app:ci_margin="5dp"
    app:ci_orientation="horizontal"
    app:ci_gravity="center"/>
```

And the code of my `Fragment`:

```
@Override
@NonNull
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* Inflate the data-binding */
    this.mDataBinding = DialogManualBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    /* FragmentStateAdapter */
    ManualPagerAdapter adapter = new ManualPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
    this.mDataBinding.pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    /* CircleIndicator3 */
    this.mDataBinding.indicator.setViewPager(this.mDataBinding.pager);

    /* Optional */
    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(this.mDataBinding.indicator.getAdapterDataObserver());

    return this.mDataBinding.getRoot();
}
```